# Diagnose an error of .net core 3.1 service in Linux OS

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1

I had an asp.net service on **.net core 3.1**., migrated from **.net core 2.2**.
The **.net core 3.1** version works well in Windows environment.
The **.net core 2.2** version works well in Linux evironment.
But the **.net core 3.1** version immidately fails after starting in Linux enviroment.
Application's log file is empty. Is there in linux something like windows system journals to find out what's happen with service, to find the fault reason?
Service published as Self-Contained, runtime=linux-x64.

Comment: We can't help you or reproduce a problem without seeing your code

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski, what part of code necessary? Program.cs an Startup.cs is a typical. I didn't ask resolve problems in code, I ask about tools to "catch" the problem.